# Flash memory programming failure

Tags: embedded, flash, flash-memories

I'm working on an XScale PXA270 with NOR Flash on Chip select 0.

Due to the obsolescence of the previous flash, my company changed it for an AMD/Spansion compatible MX29GL128.

I'm trying to write on it using Lauterbach JTAG.

Here is my script :     https://pastebin.com/jcjsbwE3

```
; reset the FLASH declaration
FLASH.CFI 0x00000000 L
; declare FLASH sectors via
; CFI query
;FLASH.CHANGEtype ALL AM29F100
; change type to AM29F100 to use "word wise" mode
FLASH.UNLOCK ALL
; unlock FLASH if required
FLASH.ReProgram ALL
; enable the FLASH for programming
;Data.LOAD.auto /home/lai/devel/uboot-2017-01/u-boot.bin
Data.LOAD.binary /tftpboot/u-boot-rioms-pxa270.bin D:0x00000000--0x1FFFF
; load the programming file
FLASH.ReProgram off
; program the FLASH and disable
; the FLASH programming
```

But I get an error.

> Flash programming error around address SD:`0x7C`.

On this picture, you can see the commands on the bus and the error:

[image: screenshot of commands and error message]

Have you any ideas? I've been stuck on it for many days.

Comment: Did this work with the previous part?  Compare the data sheets.  Do you have access to see / change the operations generated by the software?  JTAG would be a slow way to do this anyway, can you preload U-Boot before soldering and use that to flash the system image?

Comment: Interesting. 0x7C is when you first see 5 consecutive address bits set. I would check the output levels on the address pins.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Yes it work with the previous part but thé previous part was an Intel P33 compatible memory.

Comment: @PeterSmith : 0x7C is the last address of the datas writen. the 4th command from the end (0x00290029) is the "write to buffer program confirm". Then, 2 read are done to check the data (or pin toggle).
In our case, we only read 0xFF => flash empty

Comment: We have resolved our issue. It was the WP# pin not driven to high level.
It seems on this flash, the WP# lock all the sectors instead of locking only the locked one like in the previous one.
Thank's for support